# Facebook canvas web app doesn't show in iOS facebook app

Tags: android, ios, facebook, canvas

I've got a simple Facebook canvas web app. Works fine on desktop. We are trying to make it work inside the relevant android and iOS Facebook apps, without it popping the user out of the facebook app into the mobile browser.

This is no problem for Android. The canvas app url displays inside the facebook android app and keeps the user logged in.

However, the iOS version just shows: "Either this application has not configured its mobile web URL or the URL could not be verified as owned by the application. Unable to redirect"

If we add a Mobile Web URL, this solves the problem for iOS, but it then causes the Android to pop out of the facebook app and opens it up in a browser which requires the users to login to facebook again.

Any ideas / work arounds?